# Periodic motion, Rotatory motion, and uniform circular motion, are these same or should be considered different?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, solid-mechanics

In a job interview, I was asked that question: are the periodic, rotatory and uniform circular motions are same and are simple harmonic motion?

As for as my knowledge is concerned, every rotatory motion is periodic motion but not every periodic motion is rotatory. 
Rotatory motion is the circular motion but is not always uniform circular motion. Can we consider every circular motion as rotatory motion?

Kindly clarify me, if possible.

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/354203/is-closed-phase-trajectory-a-necessary-feature-of-any-one-dimensional-periodic-m/354216  ?

Comment: @SRS unfortunately the link you have given contains very higher level of discussion. I need a simple answer, explaining basics.

Answer (score 1):

For point particles:

- **periodic**: the most general of the four, it simply repeats itself after some time;
- **rotatory**: the trajectory lies on a circumference, but it can slow down and speed up in any arbitrary way, so it's not necessarily periodic;
- **uniform circular**: rotatory movement at constant speed (magnitude), it's periodic;
- **simple harmonic**: sinusoidal time evolution (e.g., $x=\sin t$), it's the sideways shadow (i.e., a projection) of a uniform circular motion and hence periodic.

But you really should check the corresponding Wikipedia entries for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer is quite useful for understanding the basic concepts.